# How to search a crash in Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, firebase-crash-reporting, crashlytics-android

I've migrated the application from "Fabric Crashlytics" to "Firebase Crashlytics" and successfully tested if the new crashes arrive.

But unfortunately, I don't see an option to search for an issue.
I see an option to "Search by user" but if I want to search by the crash message I can't.

This is how I throw an exception:

```
throw new RuntimeException("FirebaseTestDebug crash");
```

I want to be able to search for this exception by the following string: `"FirebaseTestDebug"`

I can definitely do that in "Fabric Crashlytics" using the following UI:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is no search by an `Exception` message in Firebase Crashlytics as of December 16, 2021.

However, you still can find exceptions like that if you know the method name from which the exception was thrown.

Please, note that the search works on:

1. Title
2. Subtitle
3. Keys

While the title will be too general "RuntimeException", the subtitle will contain the name of the method where that exception was thrown. And this is what you can use to find crashes for the given message.

For example, I want to find an Exception containing the message "Can't extract confirmation code from referrer url" and I have the next piece of code:

```
override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
    if (something) {
        throw RuntimeException("Can't extract confirmation code from referrer url: $referrer")
    }
}
```

While I can't find the lines using the internal message, I can find it using the method name:
`onInstallReferrerSetupFinished`

[image: Example of search]

Answer (score 0):

You can search for any of the keys that appear in the "Keys" tab 7of any exception.

Simply click on any crash to see the available keys. After that, go back and use the following syntax to make your search inside the search bar:

```
key:fieldNameYouAreLookingFor value:theValueYouAreLookingFor
```

Note that between the key and the value, there's a space. That's the only separator you need.

[Click here to see an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkHhS.png)